# Shopify /collections/ meta tittle and descriptions missing page number at pagination pages

Tags: pagination, shopify, title, meta, shopify-template

I need to add page number to my /collections/ meta tittle and description - for paginated pages. How i can make it trough code. I need example of a route smth.
As example : title at the first page will be like "Our title" and if we will go to the second page we should have "Our title - page 2". For now all pages with pagination has the title from the first one. If someone has solve this problem pls help me . Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't know which theme you are using, but this is already a part of Shopify Debut theme. The responsible code there is in **theme.liquid**.

```
  {%- capture seo_title -%}
    {%- if request.page_type == 'search' and search.performed == true -%}
      {{ 'general.search.heading' | t: count: search.results_count }}: {{ 'general.search.results_with_count' | t: terms: search.terms, count: search.results_count }}
    {%- else -%}
      {{ page_title }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_tags -%}
      {%- assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' -%} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags -}}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if current_page != 1 -%}
      &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- assign escaped_page_title = page_title | escape -%}
    {%- unless escaped_page_title contains shop.name -%}
      &ndash; {{ shop.name }}
    {%- endunless -%}
  {%- endcapture -%}
  
  
  <title>{{ seo_title | strip }}</title>
```

You can use above code. Else for your specific condition, you only need this condition.

```
{%- capture seo_title -%}

    {{ page_title }}

    {%- if current_page != 1 -%}
      &ndash; Page - {{ current_page }}
    {%- endif -%}
    
  {%- endcapture -%}
  
  <title>{{ seo_title | strip }}</title>
```

You have the current page number in variable named **[current_page](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/current-page)** that you can use for your conditions.